# Cannot use rosserial_server

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use rosserial_server for high speed communication.

But, I use rosserial_server serial_node.cpp

```
$ rosrun rosserial _server serial_node
```

I get the error message

```
[INFO] [1531356226.107258127] Opened /dev/ttyACM0

[WARN] [1531356226.117567124] Socket asio error, closing socket: asio.misc:2

[INFO] [1531356228.108342967] Opened /dev/ttyACM0

[WARN] [1531356228.119077841] Socket asio error, closing socket: asio.misc:2

 ...
```

So,What do I do to solve this error?

(I use Ubuntu16.04LTS,kinetic,[ros_lib_kinetic](https://os.mbed.com/users/garyservin/code/ros_lib_kinetic/))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297070/cannot-use-rosserial_server/) by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2018-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to  [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/)

"reboot the computer and do not use rosserial_python before to avoid any conflict in the serial port communication"

I can use rosserial_server by this way.

---

Originally posted by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) with karma: 110 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1